# Angular Directive Does Not Load From JS FIle

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My directive is not loading from a .js file. Can you tell by the following information why this directive is not loading from a file?

**My app.js file has**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['myDirectives']);
```

**I have a directive .js file called mydirective.js**

inside this file I have

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('myDirectives', []);



  app.directive('myMonth', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            transclude: true,
            //priority: 1000,
            //scope: {
            //    month: '=month'
            //},
            template: '<select class="input-large" ng-model="month">' +
                '<option value="1">January</option>' +
                '<option value="2">February</option>' +
                '<option value="3">March</option>' +
                '<option value="4">April</option>' +
                '<option value="5">May</option>' +
                '<option value="6">June</option>' +
                '<option value="7">July</option>' +
                '<option value="8">August</option>' +
                '<option value="9">September</option>' +
                '<option value="10">October</option>' +
                '<option value="11">November</option>' +
                '<option value="12">December</option>' +
                '</select>',
            controller: function ($scope) {

            }
        };
    });
});
```

**inside my index.html file I have**

```
<my-month></my-month>
```

Can you tell me why this directive will not load from the mydirective.js file but it does load from the controller file? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you didn't attached the JS file to html....

Comment: Am assuming you are using some AMD loader right? do you get any errors on your console like $myDirectivesProvider doesn't exist?

Comment: I am not using any loaders right now. I am trying to follow the example defined here. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/angularjs/1.0.3/thinktecture/henri-quatre-demos/tree/master/modularizing-angularjs/modularizing-angular-applications/30_fluentDefinition

Comment: Original article about separating the directive. http://henriquat.re/modularizing-angularjs/modularizing-angular-applications/modularizing-angular-applications.html

Comment: maurycy, I am including the js file in the index.html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have some errors in syntax.

**First:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['myDirectives']);
```

You don't need to do that for directives. I'm by no means an expert on Angular JS though, so that could be the "correct" way to do it, its just not how I usually end up doing it.

**Next:**

```
template: '<select class="input-large" ng-model="month">' +
```

**Should be:**

```
template: [ '<select class="input-large" ng-model="month">',
```

You also need to make sure you include the file in index.html somewhere

Here's a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xTthqwe2Yw7e9kO05ios

Comment: The template change did not matter but the plunkr example helped. Both answers were on the correct path but I have to choose jassok's answer because of the plunkr example.

Answer (score 2):

In you app.js file, change

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['myDirectives']);
```

to

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

In your mydirective.js, remove this

```
var app = angular.module('myDirectives', []);
```

Otherwise you are declaring your app twice (once in the app.js, then again in the mydirective.js).